# OpenCV: background subtraction under sudden light change

Tags: opencv, background, background-image, image-segmentation

I am working on backgroun subtraction under sudden light change. Is there any example code or way to do this efficiently in OpenCV or IPP? I am reading video frames, so the running time should be very fast. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to devise some kind of a normalization technique first, where both the frames (one with low lighting and other with a lot of light) would be normalized and should contain values which are very close.

Unfortunately I have had same problem and I could not solve it completely but one way to address this problem is to perform [histogram equalization](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html?highlight=histogram%20normalization).

After you have done equalization, you can continue with simple background subtraction techniques.

Comment: Dear Masad and Astor, thank you very much for your answers and suggestions.  Regards.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is already old. but i got almost same problem with this. and what i did was to reduce the intensity of RGB components of all the images (frames). for my case which is detecting car on street, almost sudden illumination changes from sunshine can be eliminated. then after that feed the modified RGB frame to background substraction such as BackgroundSubtractorMOG2.

here is the code. the variable bitshift need to be adjusted maybe 2 or 4 depend on the condition.

```
void makeIlluminationInvariantRGB(const cv::Mat& frame, cv::Mat& result) {
    frame.copyTo(result);
    uint8_t* pixelPtr = (uint8_t*)result.data;
    int cn = result.channels();
    int bitshift = 3;

    for(int row = 0; row < result.rows; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < result.cols; col++)
        {
            pixelPtr[row*result.cols*cn + col*cn + 0] = pixelPtr[row*result.cols*cn + col*cn + 0] >> bitshift;

            pixelPtr[row*result.cols*cn + col*cn + 1] = pixelPtr[row*result.cols*cn + col*cn + 1] >> bitshift;

            pixelPtr[row*result.cols*cn + col*cn + 2] = pixelPtr[row*result.cols*cn + col*cn + 2] >> bitshift;
        }
    }
}
```

hope it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem is by using the meanStdDev formula against a subtraction model. If the deviation was really high, I triggered a reset of the background model.